# Normal distribution problem.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

There is given a point K(x,y,z). Each coordinate is independent and normally distributed with mean 0 and variance 1. Find the probability, that K point is inside the rectangular parallelepiped with vertices:
A(-2;1;0), B(-2;2;0), C(1;1;0), D(1;2;0), A’(-2;1;-1), B’(-2;2;-1), C’(1;1;-1), D’(1;2;-1)

I think that the solution for this problem is following:
We should find the probability that x will be between (-2,1), y will be between (1,2) and z will be between (-1,0). And the answer will be their product.

Comment: Your approach is correct because the coordinates are two-per-two independent. Were you only looking for that confirmation or do you also need help to calculate $P[-2<X<1]$ ?

Comment: No, I just needed a confirmation. Thanks a lot.